# Azure devops Executing ef core (.Net core 3.0) migration sql scripts (From project repository) at deploy time on multiple databases

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database

I have an `API APP` on `Azure` in which I am building apis on top of `entity framework core code first`.

EF is talking to **3 different databases**

Connection strings are stored in an `azure app configuration`.

I am using `.Net Core 3.0` in my app

I have a dedicated class library for managing Domain and migrations.

I have **multiple contexts** and each one is plugged to a different database also on Azure.

I am putting migration scripts and databases initialization scripts in the api app project under a folder named `ReleaseScripts` like mentioned below:

[image: Solution Structure]

As you can see, each Context/Database scripts are put under a specific folder : DA, DC, DP. And there is a common folder for seed or initialization scripts.

Scripts in each folder are numbered (the way I can specify **execution order**).

I have 2 environments (dev and production `azure resource groups`) as well as two main branches in repository `Develop` and `master`.

This is my actual release pipeline triggered by the build drop

[image: Pipeline steps]

And following the tasks.

[image: Tasks]

Here is also my pipeline **agent** configuration:

[image: agent]

Finally, I want to execute every script **(IF NOT ALREADY EXECUTED)** in the Folder `ReleaseScripts` in my repository **at deploy time**.

I have found this [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=azure-devops)  talking about it but not in details.

Besides, I couldn’t understand much how am I supposed to make an approach to the problem;

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want to execute every script **only if not already executed**. This means you need to somehow preserve a state of what has been already executed on the SQL Server - This will require a migration table or something similar.

Therefore I would suggest to Make all your SQL scripts idempotent and then execute them via SQLCMD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files?view=sql-server-ver15

In Azure Pipelines you should be able to use **Azure SQL Database Deployment task** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops

Comment: idempotent... good point! +1
Although this is just a workaround to my problem.
The solution is to create another database and then i wrote a PowerShell script to trace and check executions in it (all this done inside a self hosted agent pool)...